# Trouble with admin URL

Tags: magento2, core-config-data, custom-admin-url, admin-url

@EDIT: it finally worked. I just needed to clear Magento's cache. In case you need to do so, go to /var/cache and delete everything there, and then start again.

I installed Magento 2 with WAMP server on Windows 10. I installed it with sample data, and I can properly access the example page on `http: //localhost/magento`. But when I try to access the backend with the admin url, I get the message "Cannot access the page" from the browser (no matter which).
On installing, th url for admin was set to https: `//localhost/magento/admin_abcd1234`

As it didn't work, I thought of enabling ssl_module on wamp, but it didn't work and Apache stopped working. So I unenabled it again.

After that, I went to phpMyAdmin, magento databse, `core_config_data table`, and changed `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` value to 0. I also tried NULL. I still could not access the admin page. I have read several posts in forums and still cannot figure out what is happening. I checked `mod_rewrite` in Apache too, but I didn't see any effect. I am a bit new in using servers, PHP and MySQL.

If I access `http: //localhost/magento/admin_abcd1234` the browser changes to `https: //localhost/magento/admin_abcd1234` after few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have entered a https link as the secure base URL and enabled the option to use secure URL in admin panel? Local host can't run https. You can change this in the database table: core_config and search path like %base_url%